# How to restrain JSON_CONTAINS to return only positive values?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

Given the following table DEMO (id is INT, cities is JSON):

```
| id   | cities
| 1    | ['Atlanta', 'Boston']
| 2    | ['New York', 'Berlin']
| 3    | ['Paris', 'Berlin']
| 4    | ['Paris', 'Berlin']
| 5    | ['Paris', 'Berlin']
| 6    | ['Paris', 'Berlin']
```

When looking for records that have "New York" in cities, I can use JSON_CONTAINS and it works fine:

```
SELECT id, JSON_CONTAINS(details, '"New York"', "$.cities") as `NY` FROM `DEMO`
```

The result will be:

```
| id   | NY
| 1    | 0
| 2    | 1
| 3    | 0
| 4    | 0
| 5    | 0
| 6    | 0
```

Is it possible to return only the results with 1?

I am using CTE as workaround:

```
WITH `TMP_DEMO` AS (SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(details, '"New York"', "$.cities") AS `NY` FROM `DEMO`)
SELECT * FROM `TMP_DEMO` WHERE `NY` = 1
```

And the result is:

```
| id   | NY
| 2    | 1
```

Is there a setting or flag that can return only the found records with JSON_CONTAINS?

Comment: The SELECT list can't be used to filter data, it has to be done in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Very good observation. I"m going through the JSON type documentation and all the examples use JSON functions in the SELECT list. Your answer takes me two steps further, thanks again!

Comment: I'm talking about queries in general, this isn't specific to JSON.

Comment: Like if you write `SELECT name, age > 50 as old` you'd have the same problem if you wanted only the old people.

Comment: A condition is just an expression that returns true or false. You can use it anywhere that an expression is allowed: in SELECT, in WHERE, in HAVING.

Comment: There's nothing special about JSON_CONTAINS, it's just another function.

Comment: Yes, I understand you, never tried that select. However, for JSON, check the documentation of the function, it works on SELECT too: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/

Comment: Of course it works in SELECT too. It's just a function that returns a value.

Comment: I'm grasping the concept: I'll have to check which functions can work in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without a CTE by using `HAVING`.

```
SELECT id, JSON_CONTAINS(details, '"New York"', "$.cities") as `NY` 
FROM `DEMO`
HAVING NY = 1
```

Or you could just move the condition into the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT id, 1 AS NY
FROM DEMO
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(details, '"New York"', "$.cities")
```

Comment: I did try with `having` but I must have done something wrong because it returned an error, your code works. Second solution is quite nice, I'll go with that one, thanks!